# vertical line test for a function

Tags: functions

The function f is defined by $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x) = 3x-4$
For what value of $k$ is $f(k)+f(2k)=0$?

How do I find k?
I tried substituting $f$ for $4/3$ but got the wrong answer
I also tried substituting $f$ for $(3x-4)$ and ended up with a trinomial but It got me nowhere.

Pls help

Answer (score 1):

$3k-4+3(2k)-4=0\implies 9k-8=0\implies k=8/9$

Comment: Thank you so much. I made it so complicated for myself

Comment: you are welcome :)